# Replacing a static field with a mocked version causing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, mockito

My production class, which contains a field, `util`, I would like to replace with a Mock so I can assert the method was called ..

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final Util util = new Util();

    public static void myMethod() {
        System.out.println(util);
        util.doSomething();
    }
}
```

My test class ..

```
public class MyClassTestSuite {

    @BeforeEach
    public final void setUp() throws Exception {
        Util utilMock = Mockito.mock(Util.class);

        Field fieldToSet = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("util");
        fieldToSet.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(fieldToSet, fieldToSet.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        fieldToSet.set(instance, utilMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myMethod()
    }
```

`fieldToSet.set(instance)` causes this exception ..

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not set static Util field MyClass.util to Util$MockitoMock$856409564
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using a static final field instead of injecting an instance of `Util`? The latter would be much more easily testable.

Comment: Well the methods inside `MyClass` are static, and there only needs to be 1 instance of `Util` within the class.

Comment: What exactly is `Util` responsible for?

Answer (score 0):

Mockito to my understanding cannot be used to mock static methods etc., PowerMock is a better option - https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock

Saying that, I'd probably use constructor injection in your class. In my opinion the way you have set up your dependency on the Util class (tightly coupling it in  a no arg constructor) violates SOLID principles :(.